# onBackPressed или как вернуться в обнавленное активити

Tags: android, android-studio

Стоит следующая задача.

Есть две `Activity` (A1) и (A2).
При переходе из `Activity` (А1) делаем `finish();` и переходим в `Activity` (А2), и
по нажатию кнопки "Назад" из (А2) необходимо вернуться в `Activity` (А1), но необходимо чтобы (А1) не сохранила предыдущее свое состояние, а обновилось.

Использовал несколько переходов из `onBackPressed`

Первый пример:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Второй пример:

```
Intent BackpressedIntent = new Intent();
BackpressedIntent .setClass(getApplicationContext(), UserActivity.class);
BackpressedIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(BackpressedIntent);
finish();
```

Третий пример:

```
Intent intent;
intent = new Intent(this, UserActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Но результат один, приложение вылетает. Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нет необходимости останавливать первый `Activity` - тем более если вы в него собираетесь возвращаться.

---

Для обновления первой `Activity` (видимо вы собираетесь получать информацию со второй `Activity`) вам необходимо использовать метод `startActivityForResult()` вместо `startActivity()`. Также на первой `Activity` вам необходимо написать обработчик изменений при возврате со второй `Activity` - это реализация метода `onActivityResult`

---

Очень подробно и на русском языке: [Вызываем Activity и получаем результат. Метод startActivityForResult](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/68-urok-29-vyzyvaem-activity-i-poluchaem-rezultat-metod-startactivityforresult.html) , [Подробнее про onActivityResult. Зачем нужны requestCode и resultCode](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/69-urok-30-podrobnee-pro-onactivityresult-zachem-nuzhny-requestcode-i-resultcode.html)

---

При необходимости могу сюда приложить примеры кода.

Comment: Да, вы правы, я хочу получить определенный результат после возвращение в основное окно. Ваша первая ссылка мне очень помогла.

Answer (score 1):

Как и написано выше, вам нет необходимости финишить ваше активити, достаточно логику обновления переместить из `onCreate()` в `onResume()`